# Grep files matching result of grep from a file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

I would like to do the following, but I don't seem to be able to wrap my brain around it today...

I have a section number, such as 45. I have a file of employee data that ends with the employee's section number. So, I can grab all the employees with:

```
grep ",45$" /data/employees.dat
```

Now, that returns something like the following. I omitted the multiple columns of data for brevity. The first column is the ID. The last is the section number.

```
38275,...some data...,45
4718573,...some data...,45
328,...some data...,45
```

Now, on to the hard part... In /data is a set of directories. Each directory is named p#### where #### is an employee number. Inside of those directories is a set of files. I am interested in /data/p####/contacts.csv. I have a key value ("Bob" in this example) and I want to find every line containing the key value in the contacts.csv file for each employee of the previous grep. I do not want to do this by hand because in the real work I will receive a few thousand results from each grep.

```
grep Bob /data/p38275/contacts.csv
grep Bob /data/p4718573/contacts.csv
grep Bob /data/p328/contacts.csv
```

It seems to me that I should be able to grep on a pattern for the filename, but then I have to crap the first grep in as the pattern - which I don't think I can do. If the only good solution is to write a script to do this all by hand, I will do that. Right now, I'm messing with sed and awk to see if anything starts to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say

```
grep Bob $(awk -F, '$NF == 45 { print "/data/p" $1 "/contacts.csv" }' /data/employees.txt)
```

or possibly

```
grep -h Bob $(awk -F, '$NF == 45 { print "/data/p" $1 "/contacts.csv" }' /data/employees.txt)
```

if you don't want the filenames where Bob was found as part of the output.

The way it works is that

```
awk -F, '$NF == 45 { print "/data/p" $1 "/contacts.csv" }' /data/employees.txt
```

prints the list of filenames (built from the first field and string constants where the last field is `45`), which is then passed to `grep` as parameters (that's what the `$()` command substitution is for). **Note that this expects that there are no whitespaces in the fields**, although I can't imagine that there are, given the example input data.

Comment: This is correct, but missing half the answer. You must pipe the original grep into the answer above as in: `grep ",45$" /data/employees.dat | grep Bob $(awk -F, '$NF == 45 { print "/data/p" $1 "/contacts.csv" }')`

Comment: Ah. No, I just forgot the file name in the awk command -- it's selecting already. I edited that in; my bad.